# iphone to send email using smtp server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

in my application i am able to send email using smtp server,for that i have enter my correct email id and password.
but when i enter my gmail or yahoo  account details i am not able to send the mail.
as i have set my relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com"; then also i am not able to send the mail.

please help me out this.

following is my code :

```
-(void)sendEMAIL{

   SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];

    testMsg.fromEmail = str_uname;
    NSLog(@"str_Uname=%@",testMsg.fromEmail);

    testMsg.toEmail = str_info;

    NSLog(@"autoemail=%@",testMsg.toEmail);

    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";

    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;

    testMsg.login = str_uname;
    NSLog(@"autoelogin=%@",testMsg.login);

    testMsg.pass = str_password;
    NSLog(@"autopass=%@",testMsg.pass);

   testMsg.subject = @"Schedule Sms And Email";

   testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; 

   NSString *sendmsg=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",str_info2];
   NSLog(@"automsg=%@",sendmsg);

   testMsg.delegate = self;

   NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           sendmsg, kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

    testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];
    [testMsg send];
}

-(void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message{ 
   [message release];     
}

-(void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error{
   [message release];
}
```

Comment: the problem is, that gmail and yahoo uses custom authentification for their smtp services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also source code from hear https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp Its a awesome code using smtp server.

http://iphonesdksnippets.com/send-email-with-attachments-on-iphone.html
use this link is also good....Just download framework from there and use that code.Its nice too.

Answer (score -1):

you can manage relay host for yahoo, gmail, hotmail etc. in this way-

```
 NSArray *arr1 = [fromEmail componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
NSArray *arr2 = [[arr1 objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

if ([arr2 containsObject:@"gmail"]) {
    smtp_message.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
}
else if ([arr2 containsObject:@"yahoo"]) {
    smtp_message.relayHost = @"smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
}
else if ([arr2 containsObject:@"hotmail"] || [arr2 containsObject:@"live"]) {
    smtp_message.relayHost = @"smtp.live.com";
}
else
{
    NSString *smtpRelay = [[NSString alloc]init];
    smtpRelay = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"smtp.%@.com",[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]];
      smtp_message.relayHost = smtpRelay;
}
```