# Sending email within App

Tags: iphone, ios

I want my App to send an email to users after they enter their email address. I know how to implement the MFMailComposer but the from address will then show as the account on the users device. I would ideally just change the from account to my apps email account but this doesn't seem possible. I have read about skpsmtpmessage or setting up your own SMTP, can someone advise me on the best approach?

Comment: I know you're asking about iOS, but you might [check out my answer to a similar BlackBerry question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14257538/119114).  The code won't help you directly, obviously, but the general discussion might help on your search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MFMailComposer, it will by default use device mail account. If you want to use some application specific mail account, then use SMTP protocol, refer this link

[iphone to send email using smtp server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914020/iphone-to-send-email-using-smtp-server)

If might be useful for you.

Comment: If any application sending mail using some smtp library as SKSMTP instead of using MFMailComposer will the app be rejected by apple?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I guess they will not reject it, because this library is quiet older and so many people has used that.